# How to set security layer on RabbitMQ in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've implemented a RabbitMQ message service in nodejs using amqplib package.

The producer/consumer are able to send/receive messages.

How do I apply security or authentication so that only verified or authorised producers/consumers can send and receive messages using nodejs.